# what are correct sizes for navigation drawer header images?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image, image-size, navigation-drawer

I want to set an image as navigation drawer header image, but I don't know the correct sizes to fit all devices. What are the correct sizes in pixels?

Answer (score 4):

From the answer given by Angad Singh to this question: [Background image dimension for Navigation Drawer header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124740/background-image-dimension-for-navigation-drawer-header), these are the dimensions:

- mdpi: 384 x 216 px
- hdpi: 576 x 324 px
- xhdpi: 768 x 432 px
- xxhdpi: 1152 x 648 px
- xxxhdpi: 1728 x 972 px

Note that all sizes follow a 16:9 ratio, as requested by material design guidelines. The xxxhdpi could be optional, as the image could be too large and it seems not even Google uses this size in some of their apps (I'm not using it on my app either).

Answer (score 0):

You can find navigation drawer specs here:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: its not mention there